# How can you tell which selenium driver caused an issue in multi-browser testing

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using multiple webdriver through concurrent.futures. I can't find a way to identify which browser breaks. Is there any way to identify which browser/iteration of my code is breaking?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\TA\anaconda3\envs\virtual_workspace\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 360, in find_element_by_id
    return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
  File "C:\Users\TA\anaconda3\envs\virtual_workspace\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Users\TA\anaconda3\envs\virtual_workspace\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\TA\anaconda3\envs\virtual_workspace\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="txtPassword"]"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=84.0.4147.135)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a tearDown method designed in your code, you can include some logs there and in this way you will know driver's ID and you can distinguish them.